# asp.net data binding of big data without paging

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datagrid

My client has a asp.net application, using ajax, he has a datagrid that shows a large amount of data.
Obviously that causes the data to load very slow, the client does not want any paging solutions (he used to working with excel spreedshits so he wants to see all the data at once).

Is there a solution for binding the data to the grid in chunks, with out paging?

Thanks,

Gilad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding in chunks without paging is usually called *virtual* mode. Some component manufacturers seem to support such mode on their grids. Personally I've never used such features in web applications.

Take a look at this demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/virtualscrollpaging/defaultcs.aspx